# Aura Component does not recognize "onload" attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a list of messages and I am trying to automatically scroll down to the bottom of the messages whenever I open the message window. So I tried to call method from LWC controller using "**onload**" attribute in **.cmp**. The problem is nothing happened if I use **onload** but if directly call body of my method in console it works.
Here is how it looks where I am trying to use **onload** (the messages will be listed inside a **messages** class):

```
...
<div class="messages" id="scroll" onload="{! c.scrollPage }">
...
```

and here is my method in controller:

```
    scrollPage: function(component, event, helper) {
        document.getElementById("scroll"); 
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("scroll");
        myDiv.scrollTop =myDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
```

I was researching and found that I can not use **onload** inside a **div** tag but I must not change the **div** tags I found because I do not know if I can cause other problems related to **CSS** or **JS**...

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You need to go back to the beginning and explain what you're trying to do. We can help you, but we need the original problem. You can [edit] your question to state your original problem. Also, this is clearly an Aura component, not a LWC. They are two different technologies.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). This allows you to perform some logic after an element is modified. I wrote a simple example app to help you get started. Note that you use `component.find` instead of `document.getElementById`, `aura:id` instead of `id`, and the use of `$A.getCallback` to make sure you're in the Aura life cycle so you can access the component correctly.

## CMP

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="messages" type="List" default="[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:button label="Add" onclick="{!c.add}" />
    <hr />
    <div class="messages" aura:id="container">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.messages}" var="message">
            <div>{!message}</div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

---

## Controller

```
({
    init: function(c, e, h) {
        // Wait until the initial render has occurred.
        // We could also do this in the "render" method of the renderer file.
        setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {
            const container = c.find("container").getElement();
            const config = { childList: true };
            const callback = function(mutation, observer) {
                container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
            };
            const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
            observer.observe(container, config);
        }));
    },
    add: function(c, e, h) {
        let messages = c.get("v.messages");
        messages.push(`This is message number ${messages.length+1}`);
        c.set("v.messages", messages);
    }
})
```

---

## CSS

```
.THIS.messages {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 7em;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and this answer, it is awesome.. but the only problem  here is **I do not want to have any button (in this example we have an Add button)**? Or actually it is not up to me, for me it is ok if we use button, but the requirement is to have it automatically without clicking to any button. That is the reason why I tried to make it using **onload** attribute (to trigger it immediately when I open the message window). Thanks one more time.

Comment: @mhdev `onload` is a property of `window`, `img`, and a few other types, not a global property. You can't just put it wherever you want. That said, MutationObserver should serve you well here; when the div is updated (childList becomes modified), then the div will scroll to the bottom. If you need it to happen only once, you can disconnect the MutationObserver after the first time it fires (that's in the docs).